# Input::file empty

Tags: laravel, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to upload a file and it do this:

HTML:

```
{!!Form::open(['route'=>'radicado.update','method'=>'PUT', 'action' => 'RadicadoController@update', 'id' => 'radicado' , 'files' => true])!!}   


{!!Form::file('archivoNuevaVersion', ['id'=>'archivoNuevaVersion']) !!}
```

And on the controller:

```
$file = Input::file('archivoNuevaVersion');
if ($file != '') 
    {
        $ruta = public_path() . '/repositorio/'.$carpeta['directorioSerie']."/".$carpeta['directorioSubSerie']."/".$carpeta['directorioDocumento']."/";
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();    
        $destinationPath = $ruta.$filename;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Upload file";
    }
```

But always the condition is on the else.
What is the right way to upload files to laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Forms support only GET and POST methods, PUT is not supported.

```
{!!Form::open(['route'=>'radicado.update','method'=>'POST', 'action' => 'RadicadoController@update', 'id' => 'radicado' , 'files' => true])!!}

{!!Form::file('archivoNuevaVersion', ['id'=>'archivoNuevaVersion']) !!}
```

You should modify the controller as follows:

```
if (Input::hasFile('archivoNuevaVersion')) 
{
    $file = Input::file('archivoNuevaVersion');
    $ruta = public_path() . '/repositorio/'.$carpeta['directorioSerie']."/".$carpeta['directorioSubSerie']."/".$carpeta['directorioDocumento']."/";
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();    
    $destinationPath = $ruta.$filename;
}
else
{
    echo "Upload file";
}
```

Comment: I have already tried and tells me: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219. Routes will be something or it should be?

Comment: Post up your routes.php for the controller you are trying to hit.

Comment: Is this: Route::post('update','RadicadoController@update');

Comment: After updating the relevant route from `put` to `post`, you should not be getting `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. What is the error message being displayed now, if there is still an error?

Comment: I'm still having the same error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219.

Comment: Share your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have problem with your php.ini configuration. Try to update the following variables.

```
upload_max_filesize=1G
post_max_size=2G
memory_limit = 3G
```